# ошибка при выполнения скрипта python

Tags: python

Вылетает вот такая ошибка при попытке создать проект в MavenMate

```
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stepan/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/MavensMate/lib/mm_interface.py", line 327, in run
    response_body = '\n'.join(mm_response)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python3.3/threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/stepan/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/MavensMate/lib/mm_interface.py", line 331, in run
    strs.append(line.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 139: invalid start byte
```

Вот участок кода на который ругается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже, в `mm_response` встретились байтовые строки

Comment: Не нужно код в виде картинки вставлять. Показанный фрагмент намекает, что проблема с чтением вывода из дочернего процесса. Следует `universal_newlines=True` в `subprocess.Popen` передать или использовать `io.TextIOWrapper()`, чтобы свою кодировку передать. Также следует одновременно оба потока читать, в противном случае повиснуть могут процессы, если достаточно вывода дочерний процесс произведёт.

Answer (score 3):

1. Посмотрите на 327 строчку, у Вас там в mm_response находятся байти, а при помощи метода join(), вы пытаетесь их соединить с str, вот на это у вас и ругается. Как варант можно сделать так:
   **b'\n'.join(mm_response)**
   или
   **'\n'.join(mm_response.decode('utf-8','replace'))**
2. В строке 331 не получается раскодировать строку с байтами в utf-8 кодировку, ругается на какой-то символ, сделайте попробуйте вот так **strs.append(line.decode('utf-8', 'replace'))**, и увидите ваш символ будет обозначен '?', там уже сообразите что вам мешает по логике с текстом.